# How to get the formula for a chance distribution when rolling a weighted value multiple times and getting the highest value

Tags: probability

It's related to a game. I have items with 4 values (1 lowest & 4 is highest). Each round I spin a wheel to get an item. The chances are in the table below.
Now imagine I spin the wheel 2 times per round and take highest value item from the 2 spins. That means the distribution of chances will be shifted towards higher values the more spins I do.

|  | 1 Spin | 2 Spins | 3 Spins |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Value 1 | 40% | 16% | 6.4% |
| Value 2 | 30% | 33% | ? |
| Value 3 | 20% | 32% | ? |
| Value 4 | 10% | 19% | 27.1% |

I was able to determine the chances of 2 spins per round via a matrix and almost brute force it.

However, I'm quite lost on how to calculate the chance distribution for 3 spins or more. What would the equation be for those? I only figured for Value 1 it's: 0.4<sup>amount of spins</sup> and for Value 4 it's: 1-(1-0.1)<sup>amount of spins</sup> (I think). So Value 3 with 3 spins would be 6.4% and Value 4 with 3 spins would be 27.1%. But for Value 2 and 3 I am clueless what the equation to get those values would be.

Comment: Have you ever taken a college course in probability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your results are right so far. You always have to regard the order. Let's denote $a,b,c,d$ the events, that the value $1,2,3$ or $4$ occurs. If the value 2 is the maximum value, then we have the following sequences: $bbb, bba, bab, abb, aab, aba, baa$. The sequences with the same number of a and b have the same probability to occur. We need at least one $b$. The sum of the corresponding probabilities is

$$P(X=2)=0.3^3+3\cdot 0.3^2\cdot 0.4+3\cdot 0.3\cdot 0.4^2=0.279$$

Similar sequences can be written for the event, where the value 3 is the maximum value. I omit the different orders here. We can regard them by adding a factor, see the brackets:  $ccc,cca(3),ccb(3),caa(3),cbb(3),cba(6)$. Thus

$$P(X=3)=0.2^3+3\cdot (0.2^2\cdot 0.4+0.2^2\cdot 0.3+0.4^2\cdot 0.2+0.3^2\cdot 0.2)+6\cdot 0.2\cdot 0.3\cdot 0.4$$

$=0.386$

The calculation can be managed by using the multinomial distribution ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution)) . We just have to ensure that we have at least one $c$. So $c$ starts at 1.

$$\sum\limits_{c=1}^3 \sum\limits_{b=0}^2 \binom{3}{b, c}\cdot 0.2^c\cdot 0.3^b\cdot 0.4^{3-b-c}$$

$$=\sum\limits_{c=1}^3 \sum\limits_{b=0}^2 \frac{3!}{b!\cdot c!\cdot (3-b-c)!}\cdot 0.2^c\cdot 0.3^b\cdot 0.4^{3-b-c}$$

You can see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum_%28c%3D1%29%5E3%20sum_%28b%3D0%29%5E2%203%21%2F%28b%21*c%21*%283-b-c%29%21%29*0.2%5Ec*0.3%5Eb*0.4%5E%283-b-c%29) the result. In this case it is possible to calculate some specific values in order to  gain a deeper understanding.

For sanity check you can sum your and my results.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I wonder how to get the sequence for every spin after that? E.g. for 4 spins, there are 81 combinations. If I want to find it for C again, I would have to remove the ones with D in it, then group every sequence that have the same letters in the sequence, right? I could do this via code perhaps, but is there a general equation to get the correct sequence in a way?

Comment: @JackyYe Yes. You can manage it by using the mulitnomial distribution. I'll write the formula in the answer box because it's easier to read there. It starts at c=1, since we need at least one $c$. Then a computer program can manage it easily.

Comment: $P(X=3)=P(X<4)-P(X<3)$ Is much easier to calculate.

Comment: @DanielMathias Maybe. Nevertheless you need a calculator if the number of spins grows.

Comment: Yes, use of a calculator is expected. $P(X=3)=0.9^n-0.7^n$ and $P(X=2)=0.7^n-0.4^n$ It will be several hours before I am able to post this as a separate answer.

Comment: @DanielMathias Good luck.